# Create a Mount on FSTAB Linux

Tags: nfs, fstab

If I enter

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.133:/public/WeewxNo1 /mnt/NasWeewx1
```

the backup is done ok.
I then need to put it in the fstab. I have tried the following 3 but to no avail

```
192.168.1.133:/public/WeewxNo1 /mnt/NasWeewx1 nfs_netdev,defaults,user,auto,noatime,intr  0 0
```

or

```
192.168.1.133:/Public/WeewxNo1 /mnt/NasWeewx1  nfs defaults 0 0
```

or

```
192.168.1.133:/public/WeewxNo1 /mnt/NasWeewx1  nfs _netdev,defaults 0 0
```

Comment: What is the output of `mount -v` with any of the entries in fstab? Does anything show up in `dmesg` when you run the mount?

Comment: after successfully mounting it at the prompt manually, look in `/etc/mtab` and also in `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mounts` for the current syntax of the mount and then try using that in `fstab`.  Also check out https://serverfault.com/questions/267609/how-to-understand-etc-mtab

Answer (score 1):

When mounting a NFS filesystem manually, did you start any NFS-related services before that? Did you make sure those services are also configured to start at boot?

In a Debian system that's using `systemd`, you might need a `x-systemd.automount` option in addition to `_netdev`.